# Cakephp TreeBehaviour and missing functionality for parent_it varchar (36)

Tags: cakephp, tree, uuid

I am using encrypted ids for safety reasons, so instead of auto increment integer I am using built in funcitionality of the varchar 36.

It worked well until I wanted to use tree behaviour.

**The problem:**

Tree structure uses "**lft**" and "**rght**" columns in database, in order to position child element and render tree list. When I am trying to save parent_id as **varchar 36** (5527be8e-1760-4fe4-89e5-54d811150b76). I am getting an error - cake is trying to **+2 the above string id**, which doesn't compute since obviously we **can not add number to string value**.

[image]

I'd love to solve this nicely, ideally by improving the CakePHP TreeBehaviour.php

Comment: You should NOT use VARchar, but char(36) or binary(36) as documented. VARchar will not work. And furthermore, use INT for lft/rght fields as documented.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can `+ 2` on a string, it just won't give you the expected result, also `lft` and `rght` are supposed to be always integers, they have nothing to do with primary keys, but only with the tree order.

However, a `+` on a string would not trigger that error, it stems more likely from the

```
... >= AND NOT ...
```

part.

You may to [**report this as an issue**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) over at GitHub in in case you are properly using integers for the `lft` and `rght` fields, and all you did was changing the `parent_id` field to use UUIDs.